# The "Forward Message" step in a Macintosh Mail rule doesn't forward the mail?

Tags: mac, apple-mail, email-filter

I set up a rule on our MacIntosh in my wife's mail account to take several steps if mail is received from a particular sender:

1. Move the message to a particular folder
2. Forward the message to my account
3. Flag the message
4. Stop Processing Rules

- Step 1 works just fine.
- Step 2 does not work. I do not receive the message and there is
  nothing in the "Sent" folder
- Step 3 works
- Step 4, who knows?

Any suggestions as to why Step 2 does not work? Any ideas where there might be a log file where an error message might be logged?

Comment: Have you tried swapping 1 & 2, or making a rule with only the forward action?

Comment: Yes. I tried swapping 1 & 2. No difference.
I also made a 2nd rule that just forwarded the message and then and set a flag. The flag gets set, the message does not get forwarded. Nothing in the mailbox where it should be forwarded, nothing in the "Sent" mailbox. Nothing in the Spam mailbox on the ISP.